# Insert tables and other content at certain bookmarks using python docx library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx, bookmarks

How do I insert a few tables and hyperlinks(excel) at certain bookmarks in a document using docx library. I have some static data and table data in separate folders. I first want to add all the static data. Then add the table data at each of the bookmarks. Kindly help.

I have tried to create bookmarks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.